# JS file not loading via ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, owl-carousel

So what I'm doing is that when someone clicks on search button it loads carousel's html code via ajax call, which is in another file and places under the `<div id="filter_product"></div>`. And it's css and js is linked in file's header and footer where I am making ajax call. I am calling only html of carousel. Let me show you my code

ajax call is

```
                function submit() {
              $.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                url: "<?php echo base_url() ?>public_controller/search_product",
                dataType:'html',
                data: {color:color, year:year, cat:cat, brand:brand, model:model},
                success: function(data){
                  console.log(data);
                    $('#filter_product').html(data);
                }
              });
            }
            $(document).on('click','#serch_btn',function(){
              submit();
            })
```

controller code is

```
  public function search_product(){
$data['cat'] = $this->input->post('cat');
$data = $this->load->view('public/result_product',$data,TRUE);
echo $data;}
```

If i don't call carousel code via ajax call and simply place that in index.php it is working fine. but when i call code via ajax call then it's js file is not working and display is scrambled but html is loading fine. is there any way to solve this.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function name **submit** [is reserved](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_reserved.asp). You can't use it. Try to rename it.

*Suggestion: in PHP method you don't need to echo and base_url() you can use in the next way*

```
public function search_product(){
    $data['cat'] = $this->input->post('cat');
    $this->load->view('public/result_product',$data);
}
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
url: "<?= base_url('public_controller/search_product') ?>",
```

Put line `$('#filter_product').owlCarousel();` after `$('#filter_product').html(data);` in your AJAX request success function.

Comment: changed t and tried but not working. same result as before. problem is js file of carousel is loaded and after that i'm searching and showing carousel so. html and css is loaded fine but it's js is not working

Comment: i think i have to reinitialize the js file. i think.

Comment: AJAX requires a jquery loaded first. Check your `head` tag and be sure that it is in.

Comment: jquery is loaded first i have checked and ajax call is successfull and html is loading successfully. in view there is code for owal carousel. problem is css for carousel is working but js file of carousel is not working after ajax call

Comment: Take `owl-carousel` js from loaded page and put it in the main page. Or put jquery js into loaded view. The next possible issue is an order of loaded js files.

Comment: every file is loaded fine. i've searched little bit and i found that i need to reinitialize js for carousel after the ajax call. becuase js for carousel is loaded before the html code so i think i need to reinitialize the js of carousel so this is problem. everything is working fine except js of carousel. carousel is the result of search so i have to make ajax call only if someone clicks search button. but js of carousel is loaded when the page loads

Comment: and i tried to put that js in carousel file which is loaded on ajax call but not worked. now i am loading js file in main page.

Comment: Yes, sure, after each changing of the container ID you should initialize any plugin. Put `<script>owl.owlCarousel();</script>` in view page `public/result_product`, or update main page with [this](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/api-events.html)

Comment: yes i just did this still same result.. problem not solved

Comment: Define this `owl`, put this line `$('#filter_product').owlCarousel();` after `.html(data);` in your AJAX request success function. And remove `<script>owl.owlCarousel();</script>` from view page.